# Evolution paste HTML

Tags: email, evolution

I have a table in a HTML document that I want to send with Evolution e-mail client. 
The HTML table has different background colors. When I copy the HTML tabel (CTRL A, then CTRL C) and paste it into a Evolution new mail (CTRL V) then HTML background dissapears.

How can I get it to come in to the mail? I know there is a option i Thunderbird to paste HTML code.